# Subject.subscribe not firing in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject, subject-observer

I have defined the subject in my **service.ts** 
The `onEditItem()` in `detail.component.ts` passes the value of id in `.next()` and the Subject is subscribed in **new.component.ts**
But the subscription is not working. Subscription is done in `ngOnInit`  in **new.component.ts**

The value of id is successfully passed in `onEditItem()` but subscription is not working. I've tried doing console.log check inside subscription. But nothing is printed in console.

in **details.component.html**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onEditItem()" routerLink="/new">Edit</a>
```

in **details.component.ts**

```
  onEditItem(){this.contactService.startedEditing.next(this.id);}
```

in **contactService.ts**

```
export class ContactService {
  startedEditing =new Subject<number>();
}
```

in **new.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.contactService.startedEditing.subscribe(
    (index: number) => {
      console.log(index);

      this.editedItemIndex = index;
      console.log(this.editedItemIndex);
      this.editMode = true;
      this.editedItem = this.contactService.getContacts(index);

      this.editForm.setValue({
        name: this.editedItem.name,
        address: this.editedItem.address
      })
    }
  );
}
```

I expected that the form which is defined in `new.component.html` should be initialized with the value from details component but the subscription is not working in `ngOnInit`.

Comment: have your component initiated when the observable fires the next

Comment: @Maryannah is right. Your new.component gets probably initialised and with that the subscription is made after ```onEditItem``` was clicked and hence doesn't now, that there was a value emitted. Using a BehaviorSubject or ReplaySubject you would get the last emitted or all emitted values respectively.

Answer (score 7):

Subjects need to emit the value in order to the observers to act upon the event.

This means you have to either click on your Div, or switch to a `BehaviorSubject`, which returns the last value of the stream at subscription.

Comment: If the new.component is initialized when the next() method fire, the subscription should work with default subject.No need to switch to a  BehaviorSubject in this case. You need a Behavior subject only you need to somehow get the last value of the stream.

Comment: @ThilinaPiyadasun The event is fired on button click, hence the need of a Behavior Subject. Just like I explained it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your service

```
startedEditing =new Subject<number>();
startedEditing$: Observable<any> = this.startedEditing.asObservable();
```

and

```
 shareData(data)
  {
    this.startedEditing.next(data)
  }
```

and in your **`details.component.ts`**

```
 onEditItem(){
  this.contactService.shareData(this.id)
  }
```

and finally in **`new.component.ts`**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.contactService.startedEditing$.subscribe(res=>{ 
 console.log(res)// you can get the data here
}
```

that's all about it

Comment: `startedEditing$: Observable<any> = this.startedEditing.asObservable();` It would be great if you could add why this is required or should be used?

Comment: when you hit the  `shareData()` method, `startedEditing$` observe that value value and then wherever you subscribe that it will give that value

Comment: I meant why `asObservable();`? That should be added in your answer

Comment: it is still not working. Results are same as before

Answer (score 0):

The subject is a hybrid version of observable and observer. So it will show both behaviors and it is not necessary to create separate observable.

I have created a simple stackbitz for your question. Please check  (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypeadt) hope this helps. Cheers!